# What is the required allocation of a char that is to be converted to an int from stdin

Tags: c

Hear me C gods, I am but a newbie:

Trying to get an input char that will be a small int, convert it to an int and then print it out again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char x[1]; /* I assumed this is OK because my input is between -127 and 127 */;
    printf("Input your integer\n");
    fgets(x, 1, stdin);
    printf("you entered %s\n", x); 
    if (isdigit(x)) {
        int i = x - '0';
        printf("success it's:%d \n", i);
        printf("two times %d is %d\n", i, i*2);
    } else {
        printf("YOU DID NOT INPUT AN INTEGER\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is the correct allocation of `char x[1]` for this to work? In the end my program just screams at me.

**EDIT**

thanks to an answer below, this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char x[2]; 
    printf("Input your integer\n");
    fgets(x, 2, stdin);
    printf("you entered %s\n", x);
    if (isdigit(x[0])) {
        int i = x[0] - '0';
        printf("success it's:%d \n", i);
        printf("two times %d is %d\n", i, i*2);
    } else {
        printf("YOU DID NOT INPUT AN INTEGER\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It seems I needed to account for an additional char `\0`, once that was done in the allocation, then I could use isdigit by indexing the char array and do the same for the conversion. Whether this is recommended use though I'm unsure(I suspect not).

Comment: This code inevitably invokes undefined behavior. You need to understand strings in c first. Read about them, what they are and how they are represented. `char x[1]` is too small because you need to account for the `'\0'` terminator.

Comment: Please read up about strings and integer. Please read the manual page for fgets.

Comment: the supposed answer has undefined behavior.  the smallest buffer for `fgets()` is 3 bytes.  That will hold the char, the newline, the NUL byte.  Suggest read the MAN page for `fgets()` for further details.   If you only want to read a single character and have it be an 'int', then use: `int ch = fgetc();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input does not get automatically converted into an int. For example if your user typed in "67 (enter)", what you should expect in `stdin` is `char` array of `{'6', '7', '\n', '\0'}`.

What you want to do is to allocate a big enough array, save the user input from `stdin`, then use `atoi` to do the conversion.

Comment: Preferrably `strtol`, not `atoi`.

Comment: the values from `stdin` would be:  {'6', '7', '\n'}  and the the values in the buffer set by `fgets()` would be: `{'6', '7', '\n', '\0'}`  AND the OP indicated conversion of a single character to integer, not a string of characters.